# Story-identification - 70s or 80s - Occult/Paranormal/Magic

Tags: story-identification, magic

in the early 90s I read through some of my dad's book collection.  I'm pretty sure that the story in question was spread over multiple books and would love to reread it/them now I am older. They were by no means new and would either have been early 1980s or 1970s.

The main character in this story had his wife and child(or multiple children) taken away by a sinister demonic character and the story was about the main hero trying to trace the demon type down in the hopes of reuniting with his beloved. Whenever he would go home or to a safehouse, he would spread a perimeter of salt to prevent any paranormal activity and would ally with various characters to achieve his goal.

That's about all I can remember! Useless right? Hopefully one of you geniuses can give me a pointer!

Comment: Sounds a bit like Supernatural

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the Night Hunter series by Robert Faulcon (aka Robert Holdstock).

1. The Stalking
2. The Talisman
3. The Ghost Dance
4. The Shrine
5. The Hexing
6. The Labyrinth

The text on the back of book 1 reads:

> He had been a quiet family man - devoted to his wife and children, happy in his home, happy in his work.  It took just thirty minutes of shattering, obscene violence to transform him into a remorseless, avenging hunter of evil - a savage practitioner and enemy of the occult...
>   Somewhere - somewhere beyond the normal and the good - they had his family.  And Dan Brady had to find them.  Against him was all the evil of the supernatural - powers he neither knew nor understood.  Powers he himself would have to learn to use if he were to track down his family in the satanic, preternatural night...

Comment: Good answer. You should cite the blurb passage. Merely saying "this is from the blurb" us unfortunately not enough attribution under the [cc by-sa 3.0 licence](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)

Comment: Thanks @Mooz. I have changed the note.  Instead of 'blurb', it now identifies that the text comes from the back of the first novel.  Is that sufficient?  Or do I need to identify the publisher, ISBN, etc?